# disable ccTouche

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i am setting touch enable in my layer with :

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
```

later if i want to disable touch with :  `self.isTouchEnabled=NO;` its not working .
if i am trying to disable it with :

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO];
```

its ok , but then if i enable it again with the **same syntax** i get crash that the delegate was already added ...

how one can disable and enable touches dynamically ??

thanks .

Comment: self.isTouchesEnabled = NO; for any CCNode subclass strange that is not works

Comment: don't you want just add the flag and ignore touches when you don't want process it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is really a CCLayer object, just use isTouchEnabled. The CCLayer object will add/remove itself as a targeted touch delegate accordingly. So the whole question is 'what do you mean by 'is not working'.  For instance, if your layer (with touch disabled) contains menus, the menus will still be active, and they have a very high touch priority ie it is not the layer that responds to the touches, but its embedded menus.

straight from CCLayer's code (version 2.0):

```
-(void) setIsTouchEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    if( isTouchEnabled_ != enabled ) {
        isTouchEnabled_ = enabled;
        if( isRunning_ ) {
            if( enabled )
                [self registerWithTouchDispatcher];
            else {
                CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
                [[director touchDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
            }
        }
    }
}

-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    [[director touchDispatcher] addStandardDelegate:self priority:0];
}
```

as you can see, the basic CCLayer code already implements that which you are trying to do by hand. Just use the property.

Comment: the respond to the touches means that the function cctouch get called. yes i do have menus and ccscroller in there .. but i don't have to see their respond to touches in the cctouch function .. (??)

Answer (score 0):

A cc touch dispatcher and self.istouchenabled are two separate ways to detect touches.  I'm not at a computer right now and I can't remember the exact code. I'm about to board an international flight so if you are willing to wait a day or so I will update this with the correct way to remove the cctouch dispatcher. If you don't want to wait I suggest checking out the cocos2d documentation. I'm sure it shows you there

Comment: They are one and the same. See above.